# matlab find min value without constraint

Tags: matlab

I am new to matlab.
I am going to find the minimun value give the function: x(1)^2 - 2*x(1)*x(2) + 6*x(1) + x(2)^2 - 6*x(2)

I am trying to write the matlab code without using the anonymous function, but I am stuck here now.

Here is my code:

```
function minFun()
    res = fminsearch(@f2, [0,0]);

    function out = f2([x(1) x(2)])
        out = x(1)^2 - 2*x(1)*x(2) + 6*x(1) + x(2)^2 - 6*x(2);
    end
end
```

But it mentions that here is syntax error in `function out = f2([x(1) x(2)])`. How should I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you have 2 files. In your `f2.m` file you should use

```
function out = f2(x)
    out = x(1)^2 - 2*x(1)*x(2) + 6*x(1) + x(2)^2 - 6*x(2);
```

The input `x` is already a vector.

If there is only one file then this should be the syntax:

```
function minFun()
    res = fminsearch(@f2, [0,0])

function out = f2(x)
    out = x(1)^2 - 2*x(1)*x(2) + 6*x(1) + x(2)^2 - 6*x(2);
```

note that I left `res` without `;` so you can see the output of the `fminsearch`.

Answer (score 0):

Try function `out = f2(x(1),x(2))`

Answer (score 0):

Note that matlab Anonymous functions are called with the `@` operator, so your question is a little confusing, as your code try to use it.

`function out = f2([x(1) x(2)])`

This line is incorrect, you should use a variable as function argument `x`.

If you do not want to use Anonymous function you should have a `f2.m` file in your working directory or in matlab path, as the other answer says.

```
function out = f2(x)
out = x(1)^2 - 2*x(1)*x(2) + 6*x(1) + x(2)^2 - 6*x(2);
```

Then you reference the function with a string:

```
function minFun()
res = fminsearch('f2', [0,0]);
end
```